# Ajax call not working for every controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using mvc 4 ,I need to call controller actions using ajax.So I created a new scripts.js file at  Scripts folder.In my project there are lot of controllers and I wrote ajax functions for each of them in the same js file.But except the default controller other controllers are not initiated by the ajax code. Scripts.js file contains:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //END COUNTRY ................................................................




     $("#savecountry").click(function () {
            //var car = { id: 4, name: "India" }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Country/SaveCountry',
                data: {name: $('#country').val() },
                dataType: 'json', encode: true,
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',


                success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                   // alert("success");
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    console.log(status);
                     console.log(data);

                    //$.each(data, function (index, customer) {
                    //    alert(customer.Name + " " + customer.UserName);
                    //});
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //console.log(jqXHR);
                    //console.log(textStatus);
                    //console.log(errorThrown);
                    if (typeof (console) != 'undefined') {
                       alert("oooppss");
                    }
                    else { alert("something went wrong"); }
                }          
            });
        });


        $("#updatecountry").click(function () {
            //var car = { id: 4, name: "India" }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",

                url: '/Country/Update',
                data: { id:$('#id').val(), name:$('#country').val() },

                dataType: 'json', encode : true,
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                    alert("success");
                    //$.each(data, function (index, customer) {
                    //    alert(customer.Name + " " + customer.UserName);
                    //});
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(jqXHR);

                    if (typeof (console) != 'undefined') {
                        alert("oooppss");
                    }
                    else { alert("something went wrong"); }
                }
            });
        });

        $('#cancel').click(function () {

            $('input:text').val('');

        });


        //$('.deleteRow').click(function () {

        //    alert('ewewrwr');
        //    $.ajax({
        //        type: "POST",
        //        data: { id: $('#id').val() },
        //        url: "/Country/DeleteCountry",


        //        dataType: 'json', encode: true,
        //        async: false,
        //        cache: false,
        //        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        //            alert("success");
        //            //$.each(data, function (index, customer) {
        //            //    alert(customer.Name + " " + customer.UserName);
        //            //});
        //        },
        //        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //            console.log(jqXHR);

        //            if (typeof (console) != 'undefined') {
        //                alert("oooppss");
        //            }
        //            else { alert("something went wrong"); }
        //        }
        //    });



        //});


        $("#updateoffer").click(function () {

            //var car = { id: 4, name: "India" }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Offer/Update',
                // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: { id: $('#id').val(), name: $('#offer').val(), description: $('#description') },

                dataType: 'json', encode: true,
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                    alert("success");
                    //$.each(data, function (index, customer) {
                    //    alert(customer.Name + " " + customer.UserName);
                    //});
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(jqXHR);

                    if (typeof (console) != 'undefined') {
                        alert("oooppss");
                    }
                    else { alert("something went wrong"); }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Here Country is the default controller and ajax call working well.But call to Offer controller Update ajax not working .Page not responding error will result.

Comment: can you please show the controllers?

Comment: In the data you are posting should "description: $('#description')" be "description: $('#description').val()" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take project name to baseUrl for call ajax function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var baseurl = "";//your project name
 $("#savecountry").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: baseurl+'/Country/SaveCountry',     //  baserurl+"/controller name/action"
            .....
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer has a serious flaw in commercial deployments, so offering alternatives.

Yes, you need the base address of the website, but you do *not* want to hard-wire it into the code.

**Option 1**

- You can inject a global javascript variable into your master page as a string constant.

e.g. put this at the top of your master page

```
<script>
     window.baseurl = "@Url.Content("~/")";
</script>
```

then just use window.baseurl prepended to your URLs

e.g

```
$("#savecountry").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: window.baseurl+'/Country/SaveCountry',
```

**Option 2**

- You can inject a `data-` attribute into the DOM in your master page. e.g. on the body tag

then extract it using jQuery:

e.g.

```
var baseurl = $('body').data('baseurl');
$("#savecountry").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseurl+'/Country/SaveCountry',
```

**Option 3 (I do not advise this one)**

Inject the string literal into your Javascript

```
$("#savecountry").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("SaveCountry", "Country")",
```

This is bad for maintenance and debugging as the code *must be in a Razor view* in order to work.

We used to use option 2 a lot, but now tend to use option 1.